# What are the Software design patterns CQ5 supports

Tags: design-patterns, aem

What are the Software design patterns CQ5 supports(Which Software design pattern near suits for the CQ5).?

Answer (score 0):

Any patterns that you like. OSGi makes CQ5 very modular, so you should be free to use whatever suits your needs.